BootstrapVue Popover: Strange reactivity behaviour
I have a Vue tempate code similar to this one:
<b-button id="button" @click="editingComment=true">
  Click me
</b-button>

<b-popover target="button">
  <template #title>
    <div>Comment is beeing<span v-if="editingComment"> {{ true ? 'edited' : 'created' }}</span></div>
  </template>
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</b-popover>

Depending on a seemingly unrelated "condition", the title is rendered correctly or not.
I wrote a script that changes the state of editingComment every two seconds. If I make the title of another - seemingly unrelated - popover depend on editingComment, both popovers keep changing their titles according to editingComment. Otherwise, the given popover's title doesn't change.
What can be the cause of this behaviour? The problem occured after migrating to the Vue3 compatibility version.
Look here for an example showing the non-reactivity.

Needs to be debugged. Please, provide a way to reproduce

I couldn't reproduce the case with the "unrelated popover", but here is an example showing the non-reactivity.
The documentation clearly states that reactive content is possible and it used to work with Vue2.

Thanks, this looks like a complex issue that needs a plenty of time to untangle.  BPopover inherits from BTooltip and I'd suggest to set things straight first with the latter because it will be  easier to debug. It looks like it's because bs-vue handles slots in a very hacky way and breaks, it passes vnodes from slots to new instance https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/blob/dev/src/components/tooltip/tooltip.js#L198C47-L198C48 , this is undocumented and totally unsafe.

V3 template compiler applies additional optimizations to avoid multiple renders. This requires extra care when dealing with slots on low level, e.g using cloneVnode when you pass them to some other context, something that bs-vue doesn't do. Not doing this results in comps not being rerendered, this is what can be seen here, this already occured to me. Basically the compiler adds patchflags https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism#patch-flags that prevent things from being rerendered in edge cases.

A workaround for your case is to avoid these optimizations in slot vnodes, at least for bs-vue comps that have this kind of problem, i.e. use render function instead of a template where you use them, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-vue-with-compat-6vuktu vs https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-vue-with-compat-sykn91 . The comps are probably limited to the ones that use createNewChildComponent to create an overlay - tooltip, popover, toast, etc.

Thanks a lot for taking the time! I finally found a way to solve this for my case. Not sure if the patch flags are the cause, though. I took your example and changed the patch flags to 0 in the generated code,so that optimizations should have been skipped. But the problem persisted.

Could be that vnode objects are not cloned. In my case a vnode that was passed elsewhere had to be a cloned object AND contain no patchflag in order to not cause rendering problems. This is what Vue's own cloneVnode does. Unless you want to patch bs-vue to change this lowlevel behavior, this is probably a rare legit case for forceUpdate indeed.

According to Estus Flask's comments there is an error in how BootstrapVue treats slot vnodes internally.
A quick workaround is to use Vue's $forceUpdate() method.
To do this, one can add a reference to the component and force an update on variable changes:
<b-popover ref="popover" target="button">

watch: {
    'editingComment'() {
        this.$refs.popover.$forceUpdate();
    }
}

